# Prevent scrolledtext from taking up entire parent window disallowing other widgets from showing up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, text, python-3.7

So I am actually writing a simple GUI program which makes use of ScrolledText widget from tkinter.scrolledtext module.

The problem is this ScrolledText widget seems to take up the complete space available in the parent window. It disallows me from putting in any other widget in the same parent window. I have tried using both grid and pack GeoManagers (i know place isn't very useful in all cases), but the other widgets won't show up (neither above the scrolledtext widget nor below it).

HERE IS THE CODE--

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as sct

win2 = tk.Tk()
win2.geometry('1150x680')
win2.wm_geometry('+80+20')

txtbox = sct.ScrolledText(win2, width=500, height=350, bg='#fff', fg='#00f')
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
txt = '<ABOUT 60 Lines TEXT HERE>'

txtbox.insert(1.0, txt)
txtbox.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

tk.Button(win2, text='Got It', command=win2.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

This code is actually a part of a static method (i don't think makes a difference). When this is run the only thing visible on the screen is the scrolledtext widget with those 60 lines (i have tried it with 2 lines as well - still doesn't work).
The same happens when using pack().

To my surprise the only thing i could find in documentation is this::

[ScrolledText Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html)

I don't know what I am missing here so please suggest me a way around this.
Thanks You :)

Comment: Are you aware that the width and height of the `ScrolledText` is in _character_, not pixels, or are you intentionally wanting to create a text widget 500 _characters_ wide?

Comment: @BryanOakley

Oh i didn't know that. I often get confused between this (maybe 'cause of my past experiences with CSS & HTML xD), but thank you. I'ma try that without adding those parameters.

[This has nothing to do with the problem or solution - but i was actually waiting for your response on my first question - You are amazing :)]

Comment: @Bryan
That works. Thank you so much.

so i'ma mark the answer by [j_4321] as the accepted answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution with grid**

The problem is the configuration of the grid: by default, the grid cells expand to fit the content. In your case the text widget is so big that the button in the row below is out of the screen. To fix that, you need to configure the first row and column to stretch with the GUI:

```
win2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
win2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

and make the text widget fill the cell, using the `sticky` option:

```
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')
```

This way the text widget will adapt to the window size and not the other way around.

Full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as sct

win2 = tk.Tk()
win2.geometry('1150x680')
win2.wm_geometry('+80+20')
win2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
win2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
txtbox = sct.ScrolledText(win2, width=500, height=350, bg='#fff', fg='#00f')
txtbox.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ewns')
txt = '<ABOUT 60 Lines TEXT HERE>'

txtbox.insert(1.0, txt)
txtbox.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

tk.Button(win2, text='Got It', command=win2.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

**Alternative method, using pack**

You can use pack with the options `fill='both'` and `expand=True` to achieve the same result as with grid. In this case, the additional trick is to pack the button first to ensure that it has enough space to show in the window. Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as sct

win2 = tk.Tk()
win2.geometry('1150x680')
win2.wm_geometry('+80+20')

tk.Button(win2, text='Got It', command=win2.destroy).pack(side='bottom')
txtbox = sct.ScrolledText(win2, width=500, height=350, bg='#fff', fg='#00f')
txtbox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
txt = '<ABOUT 60 Lines TEXT HERE>'

txtbox.insert(1.0, txt)
txtbox.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
```